# Failed to decode output: Error: Unsupported or invalid type: tuple

Tags: arrays, struct

I have a following struct,

```
struct Funds {
uint amount;
address sender;
uint time;
}
Funds[] public fundArray;

function StructsDemo() public{
    fundArray.push(Funds(100,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c, 12345678910));
    fundArray.push(Funds(200,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c, 12345678910));
} 
function getArray() public view returns(Funds[] array){
    return fundArray;
}
```

When I run getArray() function, it returns me following error:
error: Failed to decode output: Error: Unsupported or invalid type: tuple

I'm intending to print whole of the array, any suggestions will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the solidity frequently asked questions for `v0.4.23`:

> Can you return an array or a `string` from a solidity function call?

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/frequently-asked-questions.html#can-you-return-an-array-or-a-string-from-a-solidity-function-call

> Yes. See [array_receiver_and_returner.sol](https://github.com/fivedogit/solidity-baby-steps/blob/master/contracts/60_array_receiver_and_returner.sol).
>
> **What is problematic, though, is returning any variably-sized data
>   (e.g. a variably-sized array like `uint[]`) from a fuction called from
>   within Solidity. This is a limitation of the EVM and will be solved
>   with the next protocol update.**
>
> Returning variably-sized data as part of an external transaction or
>   call is fine.

I have made bold the relevant statement. It seems for your purposes, you will need to use a static array with a defined size.